# How do I inject an Individual into a Marketing Cloud Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, individual

I want to inject an 'Individual' from the Sales Cloud Individual Object into a Marketing Cloud Journey.

Currently I can only seem to inject Users, Contacts or Leads. Does anybody know how to allow Individuals to be injected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've investigated using the Individual Object for an implementation that I'm currently working on. I'm excited by the potential of this new object, as it not only provides 'privacy by design', buy it would also resolve the inherent duplication issue that we have with Marketing Cloud's Subscriber and Contact model (where both Lead and Contact records are created for the same person).

I have spoken to the Salesforce product team regarding this, but they advised that Journey Builder support for the Individual Object is not available at this time. They are considering this for a future release (but pay attention to those forward-looking statements).

Comment: Your use case around the Lead/Contact duplication is exactly what we're trying to achieve. Would also be useful in PersonAccount setups, which strangely still manifest as an Account _and_ a Contact in the Marketing Cloud Synchronised Data Extensions. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hello Alasdair, thanks for your comment. If this answers your question, then please could you accept my answer, for the benefit of others?

Comment: From what I understand, Journey builder does not support standard objects made with API version 33+, but the April release should support these new objects https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_april_2019_journey_builder_mc_connect_API_version.htm&type=5